Windows logo missing in Shut Down Windows menu
I usually press Alt F4 on Windows desktop to shut down. Recently, after an insider preview update (26100.1), the Windows 11 logo in Shut down window is gone.
Before:

After:

I remember same thing happened on my old PC, and was fixed after a clean install. Windows updates didn't fix it.
How can I get back the logo? Is there a registry entry for it?
